# How get alfresco data List name via CMIS?

Tags: java, alfresco

Here is a code sample:

```
Folder dataLists = (Folder) session.getObjectByPath("/sites/swsdp/dataLists");
        Joiner joiner = Joiner.on("\t");
        for (Folder cmisObject : (Iterable<Folder>) ((Iterable) dataLists.getChildren())) {
            System.out.println(
                    joiner.join(
                            cmisObject.getId(),
                            cmisObject.getName(),
                            cmisObject.getDescription(),
                            cmisObject.getClass()
                    ));
            System.out.println("==============================");
        }
```

The output is:

```
a534356f-8dd6-4d9a-8ffb-dc1adb140c01    71824d77-9cd8-44c3-b3e4-dbca7e17dc49    Project issues  class org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.FolderImpl
```

Ok, description can be printed via `getDescription()` method, but how get list name? Why I got an `UUID` instead of `Issue Log`? (`Issue Log` is how list appeared in list of lists).

Comment: you are searching the folder name ?!?

Comment: did you try to use a query to get all the name ?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should look at how data lists are structured by navigating to them with the Node Browser. That will shed a lot of light on the structure of the object.

If you do that, you'll learn that the name of a data list is actually stored in the cm:title property. The cm:title property is defined in an aspect, which CMIS calls "secondary types".

If you are using Alfresco 4.2.x or higher and the CMIS 1.1 end point, you should be able to grab the cm:title property using your code using:

```
cmisObject.getPropertyValue("cm:title")
```

Also, if you'd rather go the query route, realize that the type you want to query is not cm:folder, but rather dl:dataList. You can do a join with the cm:titled aspect to get the data list title property that way, like this:

```
SELECT t.cm:title FROM dl:dataList as d join cm:titled as t on d.cmis:objectId = t.cmis:objectId
```